# Find a model through the associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I currently have the following three models:

```
class Vacancy < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Database Associations
  has_many :vacancy_occupations, :foreign_key => :vacancy_id
  has_many :occupations, :through => :vacancy_occupations
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :employer

  # Database Validations
  validates_presence_of :name, :title, :description
end

class VacancyOccupation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vacancy, :foreign_key => :vacancy_id
  belongs_to :occupation, :foreign_key => :concept_id
end

class Occupation < Concept
end

class Concept < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Database Associations
  has_many :labels
  has_many :vacancy_occupations, :foreign_key => :concept_id
  has_many :cv_occupations, :foreign_key => :concept_id
  has_many :vacancies, :through => :vacancy_occupations
  has_many :cvs, :through => :cv_occupations

  # Database Validations
  validates_presence_of :uri
  validates_uniqueness_of :uri
end
```

I'm looking for a mechanism that selects all vacancies that have a given occupation. Currently I can get it dony by the following statement:

```
@vacancies = Vacancy.joins(:vacancy_occupations).where('vacancy_occupations.concept_id' => occupation_ids).uniq
```

But I was wondering if there is a cleaner syntax to get this done? Been playing with the includes options and trying from different models as starting point but I seem to get hopelessly lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use scopes to get cleaner syntax

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right syntax, but if you can get the parents of all occupations you'd basically get a list of all vacancies that have occupations.

```
Occupation.all.vacancies
```

Comment: That would end me up with just all Vacancies in the end that have an occupation linked, whereas I just want the vacancies with a specific occupation linked.

Comment: occupation = Occupation.find(...) then, occupation.vacancies